# Identify movie or show where alien spaceship would disappear things with blue weapon

Tags: story-identification

This question was originally posted in [Movies Stackexchange](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72331/identify-movie-or-show-where-alien-spaceship-would-disappear-things-with-blue-we?noredirect=1#comment117208_72331), but no one was able to successfully identify the movie/show there so I thought I'd try it here.

I remember watching a small part of a show (movie or TV show I don't know) a long time ago. It's possibly from the 80's or 90's. In the scene I saw, some military people came across what looked like a small periscope (maybe a foot or two tall?) with a blue end embedded in the ground, spinning around.

Later, this periscope must've come out of the ground, because two alien spaceships that had this periscope on it were attacking the military people. The spaceships were somewhat saucer-like. They had more "traditional" red weapons that when fired would explode things, and then the blue periscope would also fire and anything it hit would freeze and then disappear over the course of a few seconds.

What is this movie/show?

I've included a picture of the spaceships as best as I can remember them (front and side view), seen below. The spaceships were gray except for the red weapons on the side and the blue weapon mounted on the periscope-looking thing.

**Edit:** It appears I misremembered the exact height of the periscope and the colors of the weapons.  Either that, or there is another film very similar to the 1953 War of the Worlds out there that remains unidentified :).

[image]

Comment: I vaguely remember something like this being one of the versions of *War of the Worlds*.  I don't recall any different color themed weapons however.

Comment: It reminds me of the early War of the Worlds film as well. Does this ring any bells? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0046534/mediaviewer/rm2915671552

Comment: This *has* to be the 1953 War of the Worlds - everything except the colour of the weapons matches, including the heat ray first emerging from the ground.

Comment: maybe his color scheme on his tv was off lol

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This does seem like the [1953 version of *War of the Worlds*.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0046534/?ref_=nv_sr_2)

The saucers have a red periscope, not a blue one, and the saucers and sides are green, so it's not an exact match to what you're describing.  Usually they're firing red "heat rays" from their periscope, but I did find footage where they are firing different colored weapons from their sides which does disintegrate things in a slow fade effect.  Here's a youtube clip of a battle with the "saucers" (they're supposed to be tripods, which is what the fighting machines in the original are described as, but they made the legs invisible and just throw up sparks to show where they're "standing" (thank you @Werrf)).

Comment: The white sparks on the ground beneath each ship were supposed to be where the electromagnetic legs were touching the ground.

Comment: @Werrf - Huh.  Didn't even notice those until you pointed them out.  It's a busy scene.  Thanks!

Comment: This is quite close to what I remember.  I was very small at the time so it's likely my memory is faulty.

Comment: @Joshua - I briefly glimpsed *The Dark Crystal* when I was in single-digits, and was convinced it was a fever-dream for years after.  When I finally found it only one scene really matched what was in my head, everything else was way distorted, which is why I hadn't caught on for so long, even after I knew the name.  It happens more often than we'd like.

Answer (score 4):

The saucers from *War of the Worlds* were modified and reused in *Robinson Crusoe on Mars* 1964.  See the trailor.

[1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Egf7wjf0nqU)

And stills:

http://www.criterionconfessions.com/2008/12/robinson-crusoe-on-mars-404.html[2](http://www.criterionconfessions.com/2008/12/robinson-crusoe-on-mars-404.html)

[Why do the Martian aggressors in Robinson Crusoe on Mars look the same as those in War of the Worlds?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36643/why-do-the-martian-aggressors-in-robinson-crusoe-on-mars-look-the-same-as-those)[3](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36643/why-do-the-martian-aggressors-in-robinson-crusoe-on-mars-look-the-same-as-those)

Thus you might be remembering scenes from both movies.  Or else spaceships in a third movie designed to look like those the saucers.

Comment: +1, not because it feels right, but just because I had no idea this "scientifically accurate" cheese existed.

Comment: The trailer looks nothing like what I remember.